# how to initialize binding to be property (android viewmodel )?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I want the variable binding to be a property so that it can be accessed for all methods, but I don't know how to initialize it (kotlin)

```
 val binding: pendaftaranBinding=
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pendaftaran, container, false)
```

to

```
var binding: .........................
binding: pendaftaranBinding=
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pendaftaran, container, false)
```

Comment: `so that it can be accessed for all methods` not clear what you want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To initialize the property in the init{} block

You could assign the Type and then initialize it later after doing some tasks in the init{} block.

```kotlin
val binding: pendaftaranBinding

init{
    ...
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pendaftaran, container, false)
    ...
}
```

#### To initialize it later on the code

If you like not to initialize in the construction of the class, instead to initialize it later in the code, you could use [lateinit modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables):

```kotlin
lateinit var binding: pendaftaranBinding

fun someFunction() {
    ...
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pendaftaran, container, false)
    ...
}
```

> so that it can be accessed for all methods

I didn't understand this line, seems like you want something like static properties in java, initialize it outside the class. It could be done by using a companion object in kotlin:

```kotlin
class YourClass {
    companion object {
        lateinit var binding: pendaftaranBinding
    }
}

fun initializeBinding() {
    YourClass.binding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pendaftaran, container, false)

}
```

Comment: Why would you even put the binding object in the companion object?

Comment: @ThunderCock check the paragraph and quote before the code :)

Answer (score 3):

> so that it can be accessed for all methods

If I understood correctly, you mean that you want to access a `pendaftaranBinding` type variable in other methods, then you simply declare that variable in the class's body.

Example:

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     private lateinit var yourBinding: pendaftaranBinding

    override fun onCreate() {
       yourBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pendaftaran, container, false)
    }

    private fun yourOtherMethod() {
        yourBinding.yourView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lateinit var binding: pendaftaranBinding

init {
   binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pendaftaran, container, false)
}
```

or

You can use binding delegate please read: [**this**](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/simple-one-liner-viewbinding-in-fragments-and-activities-with-kotlin-961430c6c07c) 
if you want to use val instead of var